# Javascript click once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, colorbox

I have the following javascript in my website:

```
$('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'input', function () { 
            var data = table.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data();

            $(".iframe").colorbox({href:"session_edit.php?ID="+data[0]});

            $(".iframe3").colorbox({href:"delete.php?ID="+data[0]});

            $(".iframe2").click(function() {location.href = "record_dt.php?ID="+data[0]});  


        });


    } );
```

When clicking the respective buttons on my datable 'iframe' and 'iframe3' work fine with a normal single click. However, when i click on the respective button for iframe2 I have to click twice for the button to respond. Not necessarily double click but one click and then another. Any idea why this is happening? Since 'iframe' and 'iframe3' are associated with colorbox this is the respective code:

FULL CODE:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function()
        {
            $(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"700px", height:"80%"});
            $(".iframe3").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"300px", height:"20%", onLoad: function() {
                $('#cboxClose').remove();
            }});


        });

</script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" class="init">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
            "columnDefs": [ {
                "targets": -1,
                "data": null,
                "defaultContent": "<input type='image' src='delete.png' id='button' >"
            },

            {
                "targets": -2,
                "data": null,
                "defaultContent": "<input type='image' src='edit.png' id='button' >"
            },

            {
                "targets": -3,
                "data": null,
                "defaultContent": "<input type='image' src='edit.png' id='button'>"
            }

             ],
            "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]]
        } );


        var data = false;
        $('#example tbody').on('click', 'input', function(){ 
            // on input click, set the data to new value
            data = table.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data();
            $(".iframe").colorbox({href:"session_edit.php?ID="+data[0]});
            $(".iframe3").colorbox({href:"delete.php?ID="+data[0]});
        });
        $(".iframe2").click(function()
                {

            if(data) {location.href = "record_dt.php?ID="+data[0];}

            }); 


    });


    </script>
```

These are working fine with a single click. The problem is 'iframe2'.

Comment: Your click on `iframe2` only gets its eventListener after an initial click on `#example tbody`. Define the `iframe2.click` outside your `#example tbody.click` and it should work instantly.

Comment: Pass 'e' to click function of iframe2 and write e.preventDefault() before setting location.href

Comment: nitpick: `$(this).parents('tr')` should be `$(this).closest('tr')`

Comment: you should post it as an answer @somethinghere. good catch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply move your click event trigger to *outside* the other event trigger for your tbody:

```
// Since the table2 click event needs to know about the data value as well,
// set it as a global, shared variable.
var data = false;
$('#example tbody').on('click', 'input', function(){ 
    // on input click, set the data to new value
    data = table.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data();
    $(".iframe").colorbox({href:"session_edit.php?ID="+data[0]});
    $(".iframe3").colorbox({href:"delete.php?ID="+data[0]});
});
$(".iframe2").click(function(){
    // check if data is not false (aka unset), if not, execute location change
    if(data) location.href = "record_dt.php?ID="+data[0]}); 
});
```

Now the click event is attached on load and not *after* the initial click on `tbody`, which resulted in your initial need to click twice.

Comment: Many thanks and I understand the logic of your answer. However, on doing this the button does not respond at all. Clicking on it does not result in anything. Can it be related to something else? However, when I put 'iframe2' event in the other event it works but I need to click twice.

Comment: This all depends, does your iframe2 exist on page load? Also, I just noticed that you are trying to fetch some data and use it in an URL. Let me edit the post to see if that works. UPDATE: I edited it and think this should work. Because they both have to share a variable we have to set it outside of the event handlers and then read it inside them.

Comment: Many thanks but the problem persists. I still have to click twice. I edited my post to show my full javascript

Comment: I cannot say, I have no experience with data-table. However, if you would add `alert` and `console.log` inside the event handlers you can see where the mistake is: is it the event not firing or is it the other code that does not work?

Comment: thanks for leading me in the right direction. I solved this problem by adding `var data = table.row( $(this).closest('tr') ).data();` to iframe2 after opening a browser console. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are defining iframe2 click event inside $('#example tbody') click event.
So on first click it binds click event and then second time it works.